# Chart js Loop Dataset

Tags: javascript, charts, chart.js, scatter-plot

I'm very new to Chart js and JavaScript in general so am probably doing a few thing wrong here.

I am creating a scatter plot which depending on user input could have a variable number of values.

I was wondering if there's a way to use a for loop inside the datasets rather then how I currently have all the x and y values listed?

This is my current code.

```
const values = ["1", "2", "3", "4", "5", "6", "7", "8"];
const data = {
  datasets: [
    {
      data: [
        {
          x: values.at(0),
          y: values.at(1)
        },
        {
          x: values.at(2),
          y: values.at(3)
        },
        {
          x: values.at(4),
          y: values.at(5)
        },
        {
          x: values.at(6),
          y: values.at(7)
        }
      ],
      backgroundColor: "#55c4ec"
    }
  ]
};
const myChart = new Chart(document.getElementById("myChart"), {
  type: "scatter",
  data: data
});
```